# Piping/streaming JavaScript objects in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, stream, pipe

I'm trying to wrap my head around Node.js streams, not that I'm pretty new to JavaScript and node, the last languages I really got were Perl and PHP :-D

I've read the Buffer/Streams documentation @ nodejs.org, watched James Halliday @ [LXJS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lQAV3bPOYHo), read his stream-handbook and Thorsten Lorenz [event-stream post](http://thlorenz.com/#/blog/post/event-stream). I start to understand the basics :)

I process data which is serialized in RDF (which is neither JSON nor XML). I manage to fetch the data (in real code via request) and parse it into a JS object using `rdfstore` module.

So far I do this:

```
s.createReadStream('myRDFdata.ttl').pipe(serialize()).pipe(process.stdout);
```

Where `serialize()`does the job of parsing an serializing the code at the same time right now. I use `through` module to interface to the stream.

Now I have some more methods (not the real function declaration but I hope you get the point):

- `getRecipe(parsedRDF)` -> takes the parsed RDF (as a JavaScript object) and tells me how to use it
- `createMeal(parsedRDF, recipe)` ->  takes the parsed RDF and the recipe from above and creates a new RDF object out of it
- this new object needs to get serialized and sent to the browser
- (In the real world `getRecipe` will have to do a user interaction in the browser)

I like the idea of chaining this together via pipes for higher flexibility when I enhance the code later. But I don't want to serialize it to a RDF serialization every time but just send around the JS object. From what I've read in the documentation I could use the `stringify` module to get a string out of each step for piping it to the next step. But:

- does this actually make sense? In terms of do I add unnecessary overhead or is this negligible?
- I don't see how I could give the parsedRDF to both methods with the dependency that `getRecipe` would have to be called first and the output is input for `createMeal` as well. Are there modules which help me on that?
- It might be that I have to ask the user for the final recipe selection so I might need to send stuff to the browser there to get the final answer. Can I do something like this over sockets while the pipe is "waiting"?

I hope this shows what I'm trying to do, if not I will try to give more details/rephrase.

Update: After sleeping over it I figured out some more things:

- It probably doesn't make sense to serialize a format like RDF into something non-standard if there are official serialization formats. So instead of using `stringify` I will simply pass an official RDF serialization between the steps
- This does imply that I parse/serialize the objects in each step and this surely does add overhead. Question is do I care? I could extend the RDF module I use to parse from stream and serialize into one
- I can solve the problem with the dependency between `getRecipe` and `createMeal` by simply adding some information from `getRecipe` to `parseRDF`, this can be done very easily with RDF without breaking the original data model. But I would still be interested to know if I could handle dependencies like this with pipes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes, It's okay to make a stream of js objects,
you just have to remember to pipe it through something that will serialize the stream again after before writing it to IO.

I'd recomend writing a module called rdfStream that parses and serializes rdf, you would use it like this

```
var rdf = require('rdf-stream')

fs.createReadStream(file) //get a text stream
  .pipe(rdf.parse())      //turn it into objects 
  .pipe(transform)        //optional, do something with the objects
  .pipe(rdf.stringify())  //turn back into text
  .pipe(process.stdout)   //write to IO.
```

and it could also be used by other people working with rdf in node, awesome!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will indeed add pipe support to the RDF library and make it available as a module as well!